# How to parametrise a redeclaration?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have a package for representing certain media, built similar to but not exactly like Modelica.Media. I want to allow the user to choose between different functions for a particular property without having to change the way the remaining properties are calculated.

The package is:

```
package myPac
    replaceable function prop = F1 constrainedby partialF
       annotation (choicesAllMatching=true);

    function partialF
        input Real x;
        output Real y;
    end partialF;

    function F1
        extends partialF;
    algorithm
        y := x;
    end F1;

    function F2
        extends partialF;
    algorithm
        y := 2*x;
    end F2;
end myPac;
```

I want to then choose F1 or F2 from inside a model.

```
model myModel
    replaceable package pack1 = myPac(redeclare function prop = pack1.F2);
    Real x;
    Real y;
equation
    y = pack1.prop(x);
end myModel;
```

works as expected. How can I parametrise the redeclaration of prop so that it can be set from the parameters dialog box?

I was looking of something like:

```
model myModel2
    replaceable package pack1 = myPac(redeclare function prop = if a == 1 then pack1.F1 else pack1.F2);
    parameter Integer a = 1;
    Real x;
    Real y;
equation
    y = pack1.prop(x);
end myModel2;
```

which is clearly incorrect syntax. Also, the choicesAllMatching=true in the declaration of prop does show me a drop-down menu, but there are no choices listed.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I parametrise the redeclaration of prop so that it can be set
>   from the parameters dialog box?

You don't need the additional parameter `a` to select the functions. Simply click the edit button of `prop` to get the parameter window of the selected replaceable package, where you can choose between `F1` and `F2`.
I added an animation below to make this clearer.

> Also, the choicesAllMatching=true in the declaration of prop does show
>   me a drop-down menu, but there are no choices listed.

This works for me, as you can see in the animation. Note that I declared the function `partialF` as `partial`, so it is not included in the drop-down menu. And I added another `choicesAllMatching` annotation to the `replaceable package pack1` in `myModel` to create another drop-down for the selection of `pack1` (like Hans did in his answer).

[image: Animation of Dymola parameter window]

Comment: Yes this is what I was trying. But, I realised that my example is not complete. `myPac` is actually base class in my media package and so is a partial package itself, which is probably why I don't see choices for `prop`. Should I edit the question or is it better asked as a separate question?

Comment: You are right, the drop-down is empty when `myPac` is partial. Would it be possible to define the functions somewhere else, maybe in a (non-partial) Functions package? Then they would be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently have redeclarations depending on parameter-values.

However, you can make a choice between two packages that will appear in the dialog box:

```
package myPac
    replaceable function prop = F1 constrainedby partialF
       annotation (choicesAllMatching=true);

    function partialF
        input Real x;
        output Real y;
    end partialF;

    function F1
        extends partialF;
    algorithm
        y := x;
    end F1;

    function F2
        extends partialF;
    algorithm
        y := 2*x;
    end F2;
end myPac;
package myPac1=myPac(redeclare function prop=myPac.F1);
package myPac2=myPac(redeclare function prop=myPac.F2);

model myModel
    replaceable package pack1 = myPac annotation(choicesAllMatching=true);
    Real x;
    Real y;
equation
    y = pack1.prop(x);
end myModel;
```